# Retrofit and Gson: parsing array/element-polymorphic objects

Tags: java, gson, retrofit2

I am getting response in a sequence:

```
 "parameters": {
        "parameter": {
                     "Data":"value"
                     }
              },

 "parameters":{
        "parameter": [
                     {
                     "Data":"value"
                     },
                     {
                     "Data":"value"
                     },
                     ]
              },
```

Getting the error if I call `List<Class>` parameter:

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but getting BEGIN_ARRAY

I need to parse parameter to get values

```java
public class ApiClient  {
public static final String BASE_URL ="http://.........";

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .addInterceptor(new ServiceGenerator("Content-Type","application/json")).build();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

```
public class ServiceGenerator implements Interceptor{
private String httpUsername;
private String httpPassword;

public ServiceGenerator(String httpUsername, String httpPassword) {
    this.httpUsername = httpUsername;
    this.httpPassword = httpPassword;
}

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()

            .addHeader("Authorization", getAuthorizationValue())

            .build();

    return chain.proceed(newRequest);
}

private String getAuthorizationValue() {
    final String userAndPassword = httpUsername + ":" + httpPassword;
    return "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(userAndPassword.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

}

```
@POST("OneWay.json")
Call<ApiResponse> sendOneWay(@Body Query data);

@SerializedName("FlightDetails")
public ApiResponse FlightDetails;
```

Now I called a Class ApiResponse
But How to call both 
public ApiResponse FlightDetails; & public List FlightDetails;

Comment: retrofit code ??

Comment: put your json response here

Comment: @Raghunandan Edited

Comment: @BhupatBheda Cant bro Have a huge response of around/more than 70000 lines

Answer (score 1):

This is just a very trivial issue that occurs often with APIs that have weird design choices. You just have to "align" both formats to a unified form: lists can cover both cases. So, all you have to implement is a type adapter that would check if such an alignment is necessary and use either the original type adapter if the value is a list, or wrap it up in a single element list.

For simplicity, consider the following JSON documents:

#### single.json

```
{
    "virtual": {
        "key-1": "value-1"
    }
}
```

#### multiple.json

```
{
    "virtual": [
        {
            "key-1": "value-1"
        },
        {
            "key-2": "value-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now define a mapping with the aligned field:

```java
final class Response {

    @JsonAdapter(AlwaysListTypeAdapterFactory.class)
    final List<Map<String, String>> virtual = null;

}
```

Note the `JsonAnnotaion` annotation: this is a way to tell Gson how the field must be read or written. The `AlwaysListTypeAdapterFactory` implementation might be as follows:

```java
final class AlwaysListTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    // Always consider making constructors private
    // + Gson can instantiate this factory itself   
    private AlwaysListTypeAdapterFactory() {
    }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        // Not a list?
        if ( !List.class.isAssignableFrom(typeToken.getRawType()) ) {
            // Not something we can to deal with
            return null;
        }
        // Now just return a special type adapter that could detect how to deal with objects
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<T> castTypeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) new AlwaysListTypeAdapter<>(
                (TypeAdapter<Object>) gson.getAdapter(TypeToken.get(getTypeParameter0(typeToken.getType()))),
                (TypeAdapter<List<Object>>) gson.getAdapter(typeToken)
        );
        return castTypeAdapter;
    }

    // This is used to detect the list parameterization
    private static Type getTypeParameter0(final Type type) {
        if ( !(type instanceof ParameterizedType) ) {
            // Is it a wildcard or raw type? Then we cannot determine the real parameterization
            return Object.class;
        }
        // Or just resolve the actual E in List<E>
        final ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) type;
        return parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    private static final class AlwaysListTypeAdapter<E>
            extends TypeAdapter<List<E>> {

        private final TypeAdapter<E> elementTypeAdapter;
        private final TypeAdapter<List<E>> listTypeAdapter;

        private AlwaysListTypeAdapter(final TypeAdapter<E> elementTypeAdapter, final TypeAdapter<List<E>> listTypeAdapter) {
            this.elementTypeAdapter = elementTypeAdapter;
            this.listTypeAdapter = listTypeAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final List<E> value)
                throws IOException {
            listTypeAdapter.write(out, value);
        }

        @Override
        public List<E> read(final JsonReader in)
                throws IOException {
            final JsonToken token = in.peek();
            switch ( token ) {
            case BEGIN_ARRAY:
                // If the next token is [, assume is a normal list, and just delegate the job to Gson internals
                return listTypeAdapter.read(in);
            case BEGIN_OBJECT:
            case STRING:
            case NUMBER:
            case BOOLEAN:
            case NULL:
                // Any other value? Wrap it up ourselves, but use the element type adapter
                // Despite Collections.singletonList() might be used, Gson returns mutable ArrayList instances, so we do...
                final List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(elementTypeAdapter.read(in));
                return list;
            case END_ARRAY:
            case END_OBJECT:
            case NAME:
            case END_DOCUMENT:
                // Something terrible here...
                throw new MalformedJsonException("Unexpected token: " + token + " at " + in);
            default:
                // If someday Gson adds a new token
                throw new AssertionError(token);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

The test:

```java
public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    for ( final String resource : ImmutableList.of("single.json", "multiple.json") ) {
        try ( final Reader reader = getPackageResourceReader(Q43634110.class, resource) ) {
            final Response response = gson.fromJson(reader, Response.class);
            System.out.println(resource);
            System.out.println("\t" + response.virtual);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> single.json
>     [{key-1=value-1}]
>   multiple.json
>     [{key-1=value-1}, {key-2=value-2}]

Answer (score 0):

You could use this website to generate the java object for you 
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/   just put the json response and choose Json for Source type and Gson for Annotation style.

and copy generated java class to your application and use it for the retrofit response .

Comment: Its not working. Have a huge response of around 70000 lines

Comment: This won't work. That service fails for polymorphic fields the OP is asking about.

Answer (score 0):

The problem which you have here is that for the same json field you have different types. So the first time you are getting a JSON object and the second time a JSON array and this obviously will crash as you strictly defined to be parsed as an array (List).

You need to handle this case dynamically by your side or ask by the API guys to fix the bad data structure which seems you are getting back (except if it's on purpose like that).

To understand better the JSON types read this http://www.json.org/

Comment: How to handle it dynamically? Backend guy is helpless because data is coming from third party source.

Comment: There are couple of suggestions, 1) Create a custom deserialiser for this response and register as a type adapter in retrofit, 2) Treat the fields as `JsonElement` (if you use Gson) and then decide the type for each case 3) Treat as a callback and deserialise the json response with the library you prefer

Comment: a quick tutorial you can find here https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-customizing-de-serialization-and-adding-instance-creators-via-jsonadapter for the first bullet. So for the field you want you check the type and then bind.

Comment: Thanks. Let me check it

Comment: `JsonDeserializer` may consume more memory because it works with JSON tree in-memory representations. Type adapters are more generic and much less resource consuming.

Comment: Lyubomyr `JsonDeserialiser` is going to register in retrofit as a type adapter so Gson + Retrofit will do the job automatically and it's not that complex as the solution you suggested.