# Use JSON to parse object or array

Tags: android, json

My JSON data from server may contain object or array like this:

```
{
  msg:'',
  status:0,
  data:{
    name:'x',
    age:2
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  msg:'',
  status:0,
  data:[{
    name:'x',
    age:2
  },{
    name:'y',
    age:1
  }]
}
```

And my bean:

```
class Result<T>{
  String msg;
  int status;
  T data;
}

class User{
  String name;
  int age;
}
```

Now how to use JSON to parse the data accordingly? The class `User` here is just one of the beans, there are other type of beans returned by the server too.

BTW, I am using this library in Android.

Comment: You can do this by writing a custom deserialiser but that is not straightforward. TBH, the situation you describe shouldn't happen. If data has only one entry then it should be an array with one entry and not a single item.

Answer (score 0):

Use google's [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)library

Like this

`Gson gson = new Gson();
Result result= gson.fromJson(jsonInString, Result.class);`

Answer (score 0):

For your json data you should make bean class like that then parse it normally:

```
class Result{
            String msg;
            int status;
            ArrayList<User> data;
       }

        class User{
            String name;
            int age;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

put your json response [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and select in the url source:json,Annotation style:Gson

and then try `ModelName name = new Gson().fromJson("Json String",ModelName.class);`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `<T>` in every concrete case (you should), you just need `ParameterizedType`s that can be easily created using `TypeToken`s:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

private static final Type userType = new TypeToken<Result<User>>() {
}.getType();

private static final Type userListType = new TypeToken<Result<List<User>>>() {
}.getType();

public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    final String withObjectJson = getPackageResourceString(Q43658341.class, "with-object.json");
    final String withMultipleJson = getPackageResourceString(Q43658341.class, "with-array.json");
    final Result<User> user = gson.fromJson(withObjectJson, userType);
    dumpUsers(singletonList(user.data));
    final Result<List<User>> multipleUsers = gson.fromJson(withMultipleJson, userListType);
    dumpUsers(multipleUsers.data);
}

private static void dumpUsers(final Iterable<User> users) {
    for ( final User u : users ) {
        System.out.println(u.name);
    }
}
```

Note that `Type` instances can be considered constants and created once, as well as the `Gson` instance can.

In case if you want to "align" values to lists, then you might be interested in [Retrofit and Gson: parsing array/element-polymorphic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634110/retrofit-and-gson-parsing-array-element-polymorphic-objects/43652799#43652799) :

```java
class Result<E> {
    String msg;
    int status;
    @JsonAdapter(AlwaysListTypeAdapterFactory.class) List<E> data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you cannot predict what form the response is, it's dynamic - sometimes a single object, sometimes a list. The simple solution is to first store just a `JsonElement`:

```
class Result{
        String msg;
        int status;
        JsonElement data;
   }
```